# Java Path exception

Tags: java, file, file-io, path

So, I used java.io.File for basically everything before.
But now, when switching to java.nio.Path, I'm experiencing a few problems...

What I use it for is basically loading/saving files, on my program startup and shutdown.

I use it in multiple places but I'll type an example:

```
  Objects.requireNonNull(directory, "directory");

    if (this.myObjectMap.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    Files.list(directory).forEach(file -> {
        try {
            Files.deleteIfExists(file);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Files.createDirectories(directory);

    for (Object object : this.myObjectMap.values()) {
        Path destination = directory.resolve(object.toString() + ".json");

        Files.deleteIfExists(destination);
        Files.createFile(destination);

        JsonObject properties = new JsonObject();

        JSONFileHandler.save(destination, properties);
    }
```

My problem is that everytime I do something similar to this, it throws a NoSuchFileException exception before even using the Path... But I don't know what I'm doing wrong, since I check if it exists after creating the Path.

**Update**

The exception stacktrace is the following:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: **the directory**

at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:518)
at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
at java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3451)
```

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace and line that is throwing the exception?

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)) the javadoc for `Path`, this is what it says:

> An object that may be used to locate a file in a file system. It will
>   typically represent a system dependent file path.

So, a Path *just* represents a `Path`, it's not a pointer to an existing file or directory and hence, it may or may not exist.

In our example, we need to check whether the `Path` exists, before calling `Files.list` and that would make sure we are iterating through valid path, e.g.:

```
Path directory = Paths.get("some directory");
Objects.requireNonNull(directory, "directory");
if(Files.exists(directory)){
    Files.list(directory).forEach(file -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(file);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```